# Update one column of Table A and copy the data from another table which is Table B

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert data to another table but is has some error.

Source Table:

```
Column_name     Type    Computed    Length
Are_CompanyID   char    no           2             
Are_AssetCode   char    no          20      
Are_DeptCode    varchar no         100
```

Table to be inserted:

```
Column_name             Type    Computed    Length
Foi_CompanyID           char    no           2
Foi_AssetCode           char    no           20
Foi_DepartmentInCharge  varchar no           100
```

CompanyID and AssetCode are Primary key.

My SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO E_AssetRegistry(Are_DeptCode)
SELECT Foi_DepartmentInCharge
FROM E_FixedAssetOtherInfo
INNER JOIN E_AssetRegistry ON Foi_AssetCode=Are_AssetCode AND Foi_CompanyID=Are_CompanyID
```

> Error:Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Are_CompanyID', table 'NFC_THI.dbo.E_AssetRegistry'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
> The statement has been terminated.

Comment: You must insert  a not null value into every non-nullable column (except having default or computed or system generated value).

Comment: I only want to insert one column which will be having a data and the column is also nullable.

Comment: The error message clearly states the problem. The  `Are_CompanyID` column is not nullable and no value was provided in the INSERT statement for the column. Either alter column definition or provide not null value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative is to use the `UPDATE ... SET ... FROM ...` syntax.

```
UPDATE A
SET Are_DeptCode = F.Foi_DepartmentInCharge
FROM E_AssetRegistry A
JOIN E_FixedAssetOtherInfo F
    ON F.Foi_AssetCode = A.Are_AssetCode
    AND F.Foi_CompanyID = A.Are_CompanyID
```

This has a similar effect as Its_Me's answer, but can be expanded to handle more complicated updates. Differences to be aware of:

- If there are no matches, this syntax will not update rows with no matches. The subselect syntax will assign nulls.
- If there are multiple matches, this syntax will assign one arbitrarily. The subselect form will throw an error during execution.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I realize if you only want to Edit/insert data into one column you should use `Update` instead of `INSERT TO` .

```
SQL:
UPDATE E_AssetRegistry
SET Are_DeptCode = 
(SELECT Foi_DepartmentInCharge
FROM E_FixedAssetOtherInfo where Foi_AssetCode=Are_AssetCode AND Foi_CompanyID=Are_CompanyID)
```